# Not getting value of default selected checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the of checkbox selected and store its result in an array . when the checkboxes are selected by default its not getting its value but after toggling if if a particular checkbox is selected its 
working correctly.Please tell me what i am doing wrong and thanks in advance.
here my html code:

```
<div ng-repeat="album in albums" ng-disabled="checked">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="album.selected" value={{album.value}} ng-checked = "true"/> {{album.name}}
 </div>

 <button ng-click = "setAlbums()" type = "submit" class = "col-sm-3 btn btn-primary" style = "margin-left:3%;"> Save </button>
```

here my js code:

```
$scope.albums = [{
                 value: 3,
                 name: 'a'
             },
             {
                 value: 4,
                 name: 'b'
             },
             {
                 value: 5,
                 name: 'c'
             },
             {
                 value: 6,
                 name: 'd'
             },
             {
                 value: 7,
                 name: 'd'
             },
             {
                 value: 8,
                 name: 'e'
             },
             {
                 value: 9,
                 name: 'f'
             }];

             $scope.setAlbums = function () {

                         $scope.albumNameArray = [];

                         angular.forEach($scope.albums, function(album){
                             if (album.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(album.value);


                         });
                        console.log("$scope.albumNameArray",$scope.albumNameArray)
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially while `ng-repeat` is rendering the array it will look for the `album.selected` value in the array itself, so if its not able to find it, it will be virtually checked due to your `ng-checked = true` attribute but it will not be set in the `ng-model`, so

try it like this, use a another property called `ng-init = "album.selected = true"` in,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="album.selected" value="{{album.value}}" ng-checked="true" ng-init="album.selected = true"/>
```

then try with the save button click.

[PLUNKER WITH YOUR CODE](http://embed.plnkr.co/V0vWOPDpvoJQ4tpvk9zQ/)

Comment: thanks @ Alhuck A , but can u tell how can i use album.selected array to intialise ng-model

Comment: Dude that's what i described in `ng-init = "album.selected = true"`, please check the answer again